# Selenium submit button element not interactable

Tags: python, css, selenium, automation, element

I posted recently about some trouble I was having with selenium, primarily the anticaptcha API. Ive managed to solve that but I am having some trouble over here. This is my current code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask
import os
import time

#Gather Api Key
api_key = 'INSERT API KEY HERE'

#Go to the acc registration site
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get('https://www.reddit.com/register/')
sleep(2)

#Input email
email_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='email']")
email_input.send_keys("INSERT EMAIL HERE")

#Continue to the next part of the registration process
continue_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
continue_button.click()

#Find and input the username and password fields
username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")

username_input.send_keys("INSERT USERNAME HERE")
password_input.send_keys("INSERT PASSWORD HERE")


#Gather site key
url = browser.current_url
site_key = "6LeTnxkTAAAAAN9QEuDZRpn90WwKk_R1TRW_g-JC"

#Acc do the solving process
client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
job = client.createTask(task)
print("Waiting for recaptcha solution")
job.join()

# Receive response
response = job.get_solution_response()
print(response)
print("Solution has been gotted")

# Inject response in webpage
browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "%s"' % (response))
print("Injecting Solution")

# Wait a moment to execute the script (just in case).
time.sleep(1)
print("Solution has been gotted for sure")

# Press submit button
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
Signup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
Signup.click()
```

Everything runs smoothly except for the final line. I think the program is recognizing the submit button but for some reason gives an element not interactable error. Any help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, perhaps a delay is needed?

Comment: I would not suggest you use implicitly_wait like that. Insetad use explicit wait:
```from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using selenium. Sometimes it happens that even though selenium has recognized the element, its function is not "ready." Adding a delay before clicking the submit button should fix the issue.